# Are irregular workouts through the day effective?

Tags: bodyweight-exercises, pull-ups

At my workplace, we have a pull-up bar. Every time I walk past it I do 5-8 pull-ups and then continue my walk. I can do a maximum of around 15 strict form pull-ups after a warm-up.

It sums up to around 3-8 micro-sessions through the day.

Is this effective or are the gains not worth the effort?

Comment: Are these pull-ups done with strict form? What is the maximum number of (strict form) pull-ups can you do in a single set?

Comment: @JustSnilloc I can do around 15 strict form pull-ups.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What you're doing is essentially a technique called [Greasing the Groove](https://www.artofmanliness.com/articles/get-stronger-by-greasing-the-groove/). There have been a [number of questions on here already about it](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/search?q=grease%20the%20groove), but essentially it's a method of becoming stronger in a particular movement pattern by practicing it constantly throughout the day.

Note the use of the word "practice" there. The idea is to do exactly what you're doing, about half your max reps at intervals throughout the day.

The theory, as I understand it, is that by repeating a movement pattern with good reps (which they all should be if you're only at 50% of your rep max), you're teaching your body to become more efficient at that particular movement pattern.

Stick with it for a few weeks, then test your rep max again, see if you've improved. If you have, you know it's working.

(On a side note, I'm totally jealous of you having a pull up bar at work, I've repeatedly asked for one in the office, and my boss keeps looking at me like I'm insane...)

Comment: To be fair, the pull-up bar is not intended as one. It is just a bar in the logistic entrance room to pull up things, however I have never seen one using it and it has the perfect height.

Comment: @izlin Ah, fair enough. Still a bit jealous though, I'm tempted to try and do pull ups off the door frame, but I imagine that'll result in an "interesting" meeting with HR

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's really fine ! What I would like to add is that you should pay attention to when you are doing it. for example when you feel some sort  of numbness on your shoulder it would be better to remove it so that you don't get shoulder injuries. it happened to me once

Go for it! and be carefull